# android kotlin fragment action bar title

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, fragment, title

- Question 1) How to set title of action bar in Fragment?
- Question 2) What is the problem in my code?

MainActivity.kt

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//        Action Bar
        val actionBar = supportActionBar
        actionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF")))
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.title)
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

        createQponFragment()
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }
```

Fragment.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)


        val actionBar = (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar

        actionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
        actionBar!!.setTitle("Tutorial")

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_me, container, false)
    }
```

Simulator shows that my fragment page has no title at all!

[image]

Comment: the title is there, the problem is that both the text and the background are white (it is there but difficult to see from the provided screenshot).

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code 
make one method in main activity to update toolbar like below code..

```
fun updateToolbar(){

   when(FragmentController.getFrontFragmentTag(this)){
         FragmentController.EXAM_FRAGMENT->{
            mIndexMenu= INDEX_ADD
            updateToolbarTitle("Exam")
        }

    }
}
```

and make separate class for add fragment in all other method like 
FragmentControl.kt.

```
       fun getFrontFragmentTag(activity: FragmentActivity?): String? {
        return activity?.supportFragmentManager?.findFragmentById(if (activity is Main2Activity) MAIN_ROOT else LOGIN_ROOT)?.tag
    }
        fun AppCompatActivity.addExamFragment(): Fragment {
        mFragment = ExamFragment()
        this.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(if (this is LoginActivity) LOGIN_ROOT else MAIN_ROOT, mFragment, EXAM_FRAGMENT)?.commit()
        return mFragment as ExamFragment
    }
```

and in main activity call below code add fragment ..

```
                addExamFragment()
```

and in examFragment in onCreate method call below code to update tool bar.

```
 (activity as Main2Activity).updateToolbar()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a static title for your fragment, you can do either of these things:

- You can set the title with `android:label="Your Title"` in your fragment's layout XML:

  ```
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
       android:name="com.anselmdevelopment.si.MainFragment"
       android:label="Your Title"
       tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
  ```
- Or you can do it in your navigation XML file in the design tab:

[image: set_label]